# Is there a way to display a friendly name instead of the identity in Twilio Frontline?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations, twilio-frontline

I'm currently using Twilio Frontline on top of my conversation service and my identity for each user is a uuid so when a message comes in on Frontline, it displays that user's uuid. This can get confusing if we have multiple participants in chat. Assigning a name as the identity would not work since it may not be unique. Assigning their email as the identity would not work as well if they update the email.

Comment: Hey, I'm currently doing something similar. Could you please provide me some advice on how to set the conversation name when onConversationAdded fires. Not sure if it's meant to be a response object or if I'm meant to be accessing conversation API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Conversations, the name of a participant in a conversation comes from the underlying [User resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-resource) and the `FriendlyName` property.

You can [update Conversations Users](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-resource#update-a-conversationuser-resource) using their `identity` as the key in the URL and set the `FriendlyName`, that will then show in Frontline instead of the identity.

We also recommend using the `onParticipantAdded` Conversations webhook to do things like setting a `customer_id`, `avatar` and `display_name` for customers in a conversation.

You can read more in the [How to enable incoming messages?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/frontline/nodejs-demo-quickstart#how-to-enable-incoming-messages) section of our Quickstart Guide.